# Interpreting missing slot information in redis cluster nodes command

Tags: database, redis, distributed-system, redis-cluster, distributed-caching

When I run the cluster nodes output and filter out the masters, I see some entries which have slot info and some entries do not have any slot info. For example,  has slot info 0-564 slot range and there is no slot info for . What does missing slot-info mean for  ? No slots assigned? If no slots are assigned, then the master node is useless?

```
<MASTER-ID1> <IP-ADDRESS1>:5072@15072 master - 0 1642987445000 206 connected 0-564
<MASTER-ID2> <IP-ADDRESS2>:5073@15073 master - 0 1642987446000 216 connected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it means there's no slot assigned to the master node. You'd better check if all slots (0 - 16383) have been covered. If not, you should manually assign uncovered slots.

If the master node is not assigned any slots, it can only be used to redirect requests, and it's more or less useless.

Comment: Thank you. When I do cluster info command on that host with master node, I get all slots covered as below: cluster_state:ok
cluster_slots_assigned:16384
cluster_slots_ok:16384
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0.   So why would a master node fall in this state? @for_stack . Thanks

Comment: Slot assignment is fully controlled by user. You'd better ask for your Redis maintainer, or check your cluster setup script to see if they missed the node, or there's a bug.

Comment: Thank you :) Yeah. It is possible to have some bug in setup.